# How to display user's data to textboxes in android studio(JAVA) using the email that been used to login the app that will get data from phpmyadmin?

Tags: java, php, android-studio

How to display user's data to textboxes in android studio(JAVA) using the email that been used to login the app that will get data from phpmyadmin?

**Android Studio (Login Code)**

```
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

TextInputEditText email = findViewById(R.id.email);
    TextInputEditText password = findViewById(R.id.password);

    password.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

    Button btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    Button create = findViewById(R.id.createButton);
    findViewById(R.id.forgotButton).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.forgot_password_dialog, viewGroup, false);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    });



    create.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, RegisterInformation.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        String userEmail = Objects.requireNonNull(email.getText()).toString();
        String userPassword = Objects.requireNonNull(password.getText()).toString();

        if (! (userEmail.isEmpty() || userPassword.isEmpty())){

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://cmobile.com/mobile/login.php" + "?email=" + userEmail + "&password=" + userPassword, response -> {
                if (response.equals("Welcome")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Succeed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String Email = Objects.requireNonNull(email.getText()).toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Profile.class);
                    intent.putExtra("email", Email);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, error -> Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Password or Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

**Android Studio (Profile Code)**

In this code i use JSON to get all the data that the email row have and display it to the textviews that are provided

```
        // Initialize your TextViews
        fullNameTextView = findViewById(R.id.fullNameTextView);
        genderTextView = findViewById(R.id.genderTextView);
        birthdateTextView = findViewById(R.id.birthdateTextView);
        ageTextView = findViewById(R.id.ageTextView);
        addressTextView = findViewById(R.id.addressTextView);
        contactTextView = findViewById(R.id.contactTextView);
        emailTextView = findViewById(R.id.emailTextView);

        // Retrieve the user's email from the intent
        String Email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");

        fetchDataFromServer(Email);
}

  private void fetchDataFromServer(String Email) {
        new FetchDataAsyncTask().execute(Email);
    }


    private class FetchDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String Email = params[0];
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://cmobile.com/mobile/getData.php" + "?email=" + Email)
                    .build();

            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    return response.body().string();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonData) {
            if (jsonData != null) {
                // Parse the JSON data
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonData);

                    String lastName = jsonObject.getString("lastName");
                    String firstName = jsonObject.getString("firstName");
                    String middleName = jsonObject.getString("middleName");
                    String suffix = jsonObject.getString("suffix");
                    String gender = jsonObject.getString("gender");
                    String dateOfBirth = jsonObject.getString("dateOfBirth");
                    String age = jsonObject.getString("age");
                    String address = jsonObject.getString("address");
                    String contact = jsonObject.getString("contact");
                    String email = jsonObject.getString("email");

                    // Set the retrieved data to the TextViews
                    fullNameTextView.setText(firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName + " " + suffix);
                    genderTextView.setText(gender);
                    birthdateTextView.setText(dateOfBirth);
                    ageTextView.setText(age);
                    addressTextView.setText(address);
                    contactTextView.setText(contact);
                    emailTextView.setText(email);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    // Handle JSON parsing error
                }
            } else {
                // Handle the case where the request was not successful
                Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Failed to fetch data from the server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Php Code(connection.php and getData.php)**

```
<?php

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbName = "mobile";

    $con = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbName);

    if (!$con){
        echo "Connection Failed";
    }
?>
```

I want to know what the problem to my code

```
 <?php
include 'connection.php';

$email = $_GET['email'];

if (!empty($email)) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);

    $query = "SELECT lastname, firstName, middleName, suffix, gender, dateOfBirth, age, address, contact FROM local_users WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        // Return user data as JSON response
        echo json_encode($row);
    } else {
        // Email not found in the database
        echo json_encode(["error" => "Email not found"]);
    }
} else {
    // Invalid request
    echo json_encode(["error" => "Invalid request"]);
}
?>
```